# Tracking node traversals in calls to std::map::find?

Tags: c++, optimization, dictionary, std

I'm performing a large number of lookups, inserts and deletes on a std::map. I'm considering adding some code to optimize for speed, but I'd like to collect some statistics about the current workload. Specifically, I'd like to keep track of how many nodes 'find' has to traverse on each call so I can keep a running tally.

I'm thinking that if most changes in my map occur at the front, I might be better off searching the first N entries before using the tree that 'find' uses.

Comment: If you have such a specific hypothesis, couldn't you just implement both alternatives and compare their performance?

Comment: @BjörnPollex: this question is asking how to compare their performance

Comment: Changing all of the code to use an alternative implementation is going to be a bit of work. I wanted to collect some statistics on the current code to see if it's even worth implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find will have to compare elements using the map's compare function so you can provide a custom compare function that counts the number of times it is called in order to see how much work it is doing on each call (essentially how many nodes are traversed).

I don't see how searching the first N entries before calling find() could help in this case though. Iterating through the entries in a map just traverses the tree in sorted order so it can't be more efficient than just calling find() unless somehow your comparison function is much more expensive than a check for equality.

Example code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v(100);
    iota(begin(v), end(v), 0);
    vector<pair<int, int>> vp(v.size());
    transform(begin(v), end(v), begin(vp), [](int i) { return make_pair(i, i); });

    int compareCount = 0;
    auto countingCompare = [&](int x, int y) { ++compareCount; return x < y; };
    map<int, int, decltype(countingCompare)> m(begin(vp), end(vp), countingCompare);
    cout << "Compares during construction: " << compareCount << "\n";
    compareCount = 0;
    auto pos = m.find(50);
    cout << "Compares during find(): " << compareCount << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It could be more efficient if I'm usually looking for an element which happens to be near the first element. Example: map of 1000 pairs (1, X) -> (1000, Y), which I do 20000 lookups in, but 19000 of the lookups end up being for (1, X) with the rest distributed randomly over the rest.

Comment: But traversing the elements in a map in sorted order using begin() and end() is just traversing the same tree structure as find() traverses but without the comparison check to avoid sub-trees that cannot contain your element. How could that be faster?

Comment: I thought lookups were O(logN)? Do they always start at the head?

Comment: If the vast majority of lookups were in fact of the first element you might see some time savings it's true. As soon as you start iterating from there though you rapidly lose any advantage - you're doing an in-order traversal of a binary search tree so you have to follow links through increasing numbers of irrelevant intermediate nodes each time you advance to a subsequent element. Using find() you have to start from the root but you are sure not to traverse any unnecessary intermediate nodes along the way.

Comment: How big does your map get in practice? Although the asymptotic complexity of a red black tree is good when you're doing lots of insertions and deletions it also has generally bad spatial locality and does a lot of allocations and frees. In practice, for many realistic workloads a map based on a sorted vector using binary search for lookups is faster, e.g. boost flat_map: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html.

Answer (score 0):

If it's feasible for your key/value structures it is worth considering `unordered_map` (in C++11 or TR1) as an alternative.  `std::map`, being a balanced tree, is not likely to perform well under this usage profile, and hybrid approaches where you search the first N seem like a lot of work to me with no guaranteed payoff.

Comment: Ordering is important so I can't use unordered_map.